# AngularJs + DateRangePicker: my ng-model is not getting the input text value when I select a date range

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, daterangepicker

In the HTML below, I'm trying to set the selected date range in an ng-model called dateRange. The input text field is getting the selected value correctly, but dateRange still null. What do have I do to solve this problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/1/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/1/daterangepicker-bs3.css" />

<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">

<p>Select Date Range:</p>
<input type="text" name="daterange" id="daterange" ng-model="dateRange" /> Selected Range: {{dateRange}}

<script>
    var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
    app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.dateRange = null;
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#daterange').daterangepicker();
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping plugin in directive, thumb rule in AngularJS, also load angular after jquery has been loaded

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" daterange name="daterange" id="daterange" ng-model="dateRange"/>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('daterange', function(){
    return{
       link: function(scope, element){
          element.daterangepicker();
       }
    }
})
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cEsz8aKsSI0o1xePezym?p=preview)

Comment: Could you help me. I need pass options to the directive. For example: singleDatePicker: true

Comment: Use isolated scope in directive and pass it in attribute